# Context in Django HttpResponse

Tags: django

I happen to pass by Django documentation for `TemplateResponse`. (My question is for `HttpResponse`)

> Unlike basic HttpResponse objects, TemplateResponse objects retain the details of the template and context that was provided by the view to compute the response.

Here it says that `response` object which we get from `self.client.get()` which is an object of `HttpResponse`, does not retain the `context` provided by view.

But when I did `dir(response)` I could find `context` there.

Kindly explain me the actual meaning of documentation.

**Edit 1 :**

Here is one of the test method

```
def test_11(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.signupurl)
        print(response.context)
        print(response.context.keys())
        self.assertContains(response, 'href="{}"'.format(self.homeurl))
```

Here is the signup url declared

```
@classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.signupurl = reverse('signup_url')
```

Here is output of `response.context`

```
[[{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {'perms': <django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper object at 0x000000E3FBFEB080>, 'messages': <django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage object at 0x000000E3FBFF0EB8>, 'csrf_token': <SimpleLazyObject: 'RtN0wMaL3mGQbZB3zaFjR7cNDtNLkFPvXlgigUt8582AJH2b6JYJ6d7V6UR3ZipA'>, 'user': <SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x000000E3FBFF0BA8>>, 'DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS': {'DEBUG': 10, 'ERROR': 40, 'WARNING': 30, 'INFO': 20, 'SUCCESS': 25}, 'request': <WSGIRequest: GET '/user/signup/'>}, {}, {'form': <UserCreationForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(username;password1;password2)>}], [{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {'perms': <django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper object at 0x000000E3FBFEB080>, 'messages': <django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage object at 0x000000E3FBFF0EB8>, 'csrf_token': <SimpleLazyObject: 'RtN0wMaL3mGQbZB3zaFjR7cNDtNLkFPvXlgigUt8582AJH2b6JYJ6d7V6UR3ZipA'>, 'user': <SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x000000E3FBFF0BA8>>, 'DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS': {'DEBUG': 10, 'ERROR': 40, 'WARNING': 30, 'INFO': 20, 'SUCCESS': 25}, 'request': <WSGIRequest: GET '/user/signup/'>}, {}, {'form': <UserCreationForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(username;password1;password2)>}], [{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {'perms': <django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper object at 0x000000E3FBFEB080>, 'messages': <django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage object at 0x000000E3FBFF0EB8>, 'csrf_token': <SimpleLazyObject: 'RtN0wMaL3mGQbZB3zaFjR7cNDtNLkFPvXlgigUt8582AJH2b6JYJ6d7V6UR3ZipA'>, 'user': <SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x000000E3FBFF0BA8>>, 'DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS': {'DEBUG': 10, 'ERROR': 40, 'WARNING': 30, 'INFO': 20, 'SUCCESS': 25}, 'request': <WSGIRequest: GET '/user/signup/'>}, {}, {'form': <UserCreationForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(username;password1;password2)>}, {'block': <Block Node: content. Contents: [<TextNode: '\n\t<div class="w3-card-4 w'>, <django.template.defaulttags.CsrfTokenNode object at 0x000000E3FBFF4BE0>, <TextNode: '\n\t\t\t'>, <django.template.loader_tags.IncludeNode object at 0x000000E3FBFD2F60>, <TextNode: '\n\t\t\t<button type="submit"'>]>}, {}], [{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {'widget': {'type': 'text', 'is_hidden': False, 'attrs': {'maxlength': '150', 'required': True, 'id': 'id_username', 'autofocus': True}, 'name': 'username', 'required': True, 'value': None, 'template_name': 'django/forms/widgets/text.html'}}], [{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {'widget': {'type': 'text', 'is_hidden': False, 'attrs': {'maxlength': '150', 'required': True, 'id': 'id_username', 'autofocus': True}, 'name': 'username', 'required': True, 'value': None, 'template_name': 'django/forms/widgets/text.html'}}, {}], [{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {'widget': {'type': 'text', 'is_hidden': False, 'attrs': {'maxlength': '150', 'required': True, 'id': 'id_username', 'autofocus': True}, 'name': 'username', 'required': True, 'value': None, 'template_name': 'django/forms/widgets/text.html'}}, {}, {}], [{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {'widget': {'type': 'password', 'is_hidden': False, 'attrs': {'required': True, 'id': 'id_password1'}, 'name': 'password1', 'required': True, 'value': None, 'template_name': 'django/forms/widgets/password.html'}}], [{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {'widget': {'type': 'password', 'is_hidden': False, 'attrs': {'required': True, 'id': 'id_password1'}, 'name': 'password1', 'required': True, 'value': None, 'template_name': 'django/forms/widgets/password.html'}}, {}], [{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {'widget': {'type': 'password', 'is_hidden': False, 'attrs': {'required': True, 'id': 'id_password1'}, 'name': 'password1', 'required': True, 'value': None, 'template_name': 'django/forms/widgets/password.html'}}, {}, {}], [{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {'widget': {'type': 'password', 'is_hidden': False, 'attrs': {'required': True, 'id': 'id_password2'}, 'name': 'password2', 'required': True, 'value': None, 'template_name': 'django/forms/widgets/password.html'}}], [{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {'widget': {'type': 'password', 'is_hidden': False, 'attrs': {'required': True, 'id': 'id_password2'}, 'name': 'password2', 'required': True, 'value': None, 'template_name': 'django/forms/widgets/password.html'}}, {}], [{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {'widget': {'type': 'password', 'is_hidden': False, 'attrs': {'required': True, 'id': 'id_password2'}, 'name': 'password2', 'required': True, 'value': None, 'template_name': 'django/forms/widgets/password.html'}}, {}, {}]]
```

And here is output of `response.context.keys()`

```
{'perms', 'block', 'user', 'False', 'DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS', 'form', 'widget', 'request', 'None', 'messages', 'csrf_token', 'True'}
```

Please note in above, `form` is the only value I have passed to `context` of `render` method for this url.

Comment: Did you inspect the *content* of the `context`?

Comment: Here's the code of [HttpResponse](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/response.py#L281), and there is nothing about context there, Could you share us your code?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have added the content of ```context```

Comment: @Tané even I went through the source code of HttpResponse but was surprised to not find anything about context there. Also note the ```user``` in context was not passed by me. Only ```form``` was passed in ```render```.